# Joint measure from two Markov kernels

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{X})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{Y})$ be two measurable spaces (Polish if you wish), let $K$ be a Markov kernel from $(X,\mathcal{X})$ to $(Y,\mathcal{Y})$ and let $K'$ be a Markov kernel from $(Y,\mathcal{Y})$ to $(X,\mathcal{X})$.

The question is: under which condition the set function $\mu$ from $(X \times Y, \mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{Y})$ to $[0,1]$ such that
$$
\mu(A \times B) = \int_{A \times B} K(x,dy) K'(y,dx), \qquad \forall A \times B \in \mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{Y},
$$
is a measure?

Clearly, if any of the two kernels is actually just a measure on the target space (independent of the point on the source space), then all this is well defined and $\mu$ is a measure. In the general case, I have a bad feeling about the integral itself but I cannot point out a specific reason.

Any direction would be welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that every $K(x,\cdot )$ is absolutely continuous with respect to some measure $n$ on $(Y,\mathcal Y)$, in a measurable way with respect to $\mathcal X$, that is, that $$K(x,\mathrm dy)=g(x,y)n(\mathrm dy),$$ for some function $g$ measurable with respect to $\mathcal X\otimes\mathcal Y$. Likewise, assume that every $K'(y,\cdot )$ is absolutely continuous with respect to some measure $m$ on $(X,\mathcal X)$ in a measurable way with respect to $\mathcal Y$, that is, that $$K'(y,\mathrm dx)=h(x,y)m(\mathrm dx),$$ for some function $h$ measurable with respect to $\mathcal X\otimes\mathcal Y$. Then $\mu$ is indeed a measure on $\mathcal X\otimes\mathcal Y$, with density $f=g\cdot h$ with respect to $m\otimes n$.

The existence of $(g,n)$ and $(h,m)$ is guaranteed as soon as one knows that $x\mapsto K(x,\cdot )$ and $y\mapsto K'(y,\cdot )$ are measurable and that $$\int_X K(x,Y)\bar m(\mathrm dx),\qquad\int_Y K'(y,X)\bar n(\mathrm dy),$$ are finite, for some measures $\bar m$ and $\bar n$.

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting. I guess that in general, the measures $n$ and $m$ need to be supported by the whole space since $K(x,\cdot)$'s support depends on $x$. This works for fairly general spaces, e.g., with Haar measures on locally-compact topological groups. I need to convice myself that the existence of $(g,n)$ and $(h,m)$ is guaranteed under the assumptions you mention for general measurable spaces. (I guess you meant $\int K'(y,X)\bar{n}(dy)$ for the last integral).